# Pandas styling to excel "TypeError: the first argument must be callable"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(24)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.linspace(1, 10, 10)})
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=list('BCDE'))],
               axis=1)
df.iloc[3, 3] = np.nan
df.iloc[0, 2] = np.nan

df.style.applymap('green', subset=pd.IndexSlice[1:3, 'B': 'C']).\
    to_excel('sA009.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
```

TypeError: the first argument must be callable.
df.style.applymap('green', subset=pd.IndexSlice[1:3, 'B': 'C']) without error.
but df.style.applymap('green', subset=pd.IndexSlice[1:3, 'B': 'C']).
to_excel('sA009.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') not work? why i need use "func" instead of ''green'?

Comment: `df.style.applymap('green', ...`  makes no sense. The first argument should be a callable (usually a function) just like the error says

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `df.style.appylmap(...)` has as a first argument a function that takes a scalar and returns a single string with the CSS attribute-value pair.

As an example from https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html a function that will color negative numbers red and positive numbers black.

```
def color_negative_red(val):
    """
    Takes a scalar and returns a string with
    the css property `'color: red'` for negative
    strings, black otherwise.
    """
    color = 'red' if val < 0 else 'black'
    return 'color: %s' % color
```

In this case, the cell’s style depends only on it’s own value. That means we should use the `Styler.applymap` method which works elementwise.

```
s = df.style.applymap(color_negative_red)
```